# how to use variable for html-element in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, variables

The following code is part of a jQuery .js-file (which is used in the "supersized" image slider):

```
if (vars.current_slide == 0) {
 $("#captions").children().css("display", "none");
    $("#caption0").css("display","inherit").css("visibility","visible");
    } 
if (vars.current_slide == 1) {
 $("#captions").children().css("display", "none");
    $("#caption1").css("display","inherit").css("visibility","visible");
    } 
if (vars.current_slide == 2) {
 $("#captions").children().css("display", "none");
    $("#caption2").css("display","inherit").css("visibility","visible");
    }
```

As you can see, I tried to show a different caption (ranging from `#caption0` to `#caption3`) for each `current_slide`.

How do I shorten this so that the caption for each `current_slide` is assigned via a variable, unlike my example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector is just an ordinary string, so you can concatenate the variable like this:

```
$("#caption" + vars.current_slide)
```

So in your case, the code could be shortened to:

```
$("#captions").children().css("display", "none");
$("#caption" + vars.current_slide).css("display","inherit").css("visibility","visible");
```

Or even shorter:

```
$("#captions").children().hide();
$("#caption" + vars.current_slide).show();
```

Comment: Great stuff, this worked for me. Thank you for the fast answer :)! Also thanks to the others ;).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$("#caption" + vars.current_slide)
```

An alternative would be putting the elements into an array and accessing it by index

Answer (score 1):

Just append the variable to the string:

```
$('#captions').children().hide();
  $('#caption' + vars.current_slide).css({
    'display': 'inherit',
    'visibility': 'visible'
   });
}
```